# How to uniquely idenitfy requests?

Tags: .net, random

Remote API that I'm using, requires `referenceId` parameter that should uniquely identify each request. I don't want to increment numbers because I might send concurrent requests and moreover, I would need to save those numbers somewhere (for example if I decide to restart the application). `referenceId` should be all numbers, up to 48 characters. Could I generate a random 48-place number using `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`, would that be unique?

Comment: Why not using GUID ?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate unique integers based on GUID. Look on that other topic :
[How generate unique Integers based on GUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920696/how-generate-unique-integers-based-on-guids)

Comment: He has certain length requirements for the generated values, not sure if integers are enough for him or he needs different values.

Comment: I don't know either. I jst found out that solution but maybe it's not the right one for that case. Your solution is maybe also good but i don't know if RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes gives a unique number like GUID does for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, That will be unique..

```
 public static byte[] GenerateKey(int keySize)
        {
            using (var randomNumberGenerator = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                var randomNumber = new byte[keySize];
                randomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(randomNumber);

                return randomNumber;
            }
        }
```

Aside from that, Do you have a problem in storing that value?